# Spring Boot auto-configured metrics not arriving to Librato

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, librato

I am using Spring Boot with auto-configure enabled (@EnableAutoConfiguration) and trying to send my Spring MVC metrics to Librato. Right now only my own created metrics are arriving to Librato but auto-configured metrics (CPU, file descriptors,  etc) are not sent to my reporter.

If I access a metric endpoint I can see the info generated there, for instance `http://localhost:8081/actuator/metrics/system.cpu.count`

I based my code on [this post](http://micrometer.io/docs/guide/consoleReporter) for ConsoleReporter. so I have this:

```
public static MeterRegistry libratoRegistry() {
    MetricRegistry dropwizardRegistry = new MetricRegistry();

    String libratoApiAccount = "xx";
    String libratoApiKey = "yy";
    String libratoPrefix = "zz";

    LibratoReporter reporter = Librato
            .reporter(dropwizardRegistry, libratoApiAccount, libratoApiKey)
            .setPrefix(libratoPrefix)
            .build();
    reporter.start(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    DropwizardConfig dropwizardConfig = new DropwizardConfig() {
        @Override
        public String prefix() {
            return "myprefix";
        }

        @Override
        public String get(String key) {
            return null;
        }
    };

    return new DropwizardMeterRegistry(dropwizardConfig, dropwizardRegistry, HierarchicalNameMapper.DEFAULT, Clock.SYSTEM) {
        @Override
        protected Double nullGaugeValue() {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

and at my main function I added `Metrics.addRegistry(SpringReporter.libratoRegistry());`

For the Librato library I am using in my `compile("com.librato.metrics:metrics-librato:5.1.2")` build.gradle. Documentation [here](https://github.com/librato/metrics-librato). I used this library before without any problem.

If I use the ConsoleReporter as in  [this post](http://micrometer.io/docs/guide/consoleReporter) the same thing happens, only my own created metrics are printed to the console.

Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong? or what am I missing?

Also, I enabled debug mode to see the "CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT" printed in the console but not sure what to look for in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make your `MeterRegistry` for Librato reporter as a Spring `@Bean` and let me know whether it works.

UPDATED:

I tested with `ConsoleReporter` you mentioned and confirmed it's working with [a sample](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/tree/console-reporter). **Note that the sample is on the branch `console-reporter`, not the `master` branch.** See the sample for details.

Comment: Hi, I updated your sample to add the ConsoleReporter and same thing happening:
my created counter is printed in console but auto-configured metrics (cpu, endpoint timings, etc) are not printed, You can see the updated sample here: https://github.com/diego-carvallo-tx/sample-micrometer-spring-boot

Comment: @sapeish I guess you misread my updated answer. The above "a sample" meant to point to the branch `console-reporter`. Try the branch.

Comment: @sapeish FTR your updated sample didn't make your custom `MeterRegistry` as a Spring `@Bean`.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I cloned your sample to check it out but didn't notice the ConsoleReporter was in the `console-reporter` branch so I looked at your master branch only. It is working now, Thanks a lot!